# Extracting time intervals in a day

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to extract the Time intervals by 30 mins in a given day.

For ex: If i specify the Date as 05/06/2013 then I want the output as:

```
Day                  Interval
05/06/2013           0000-0030
05/06/2013           0030-0100
05/06/2013           0100-0130
05/06/2013           0130-0200
05/06/2013           0200-0230
----------           ---------
----------           ---------
05/06/2013           2300-2330
05/06/2013           2330-0000
```

How can I get this?

Comment: Output is confusing.  Should there be a `0030-0100` line?

Comment: So you want daylight saving time days to have 23 and 25 hours or why is the date important?

Comment: @DavidSöderlund Doesn't matter. Times is important not the date

Comment: Don't you mean `000000-002959`? Otherwise you'll get duplicate data.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO No I want 2330- 0000

Comment: @peter 0000 is the next day...

Comment: 0000-0029 would be a thirty minute interval and it has no overlaps. Probably better.

Comment: Have you considered creating a table called `DailyTimeIntervals` and pre-populating it with the intervals you need? Then you could just write `select @date, interval from dbo.DailyTimeIntervals`.

Comment: How are you going to use this?  Interval is not a DateTime format.  And it has overlap.

Comment: What is the overall goal of the query? There are several ways to split the data it like this (none of them are pretty), but the way I would go about it depends wholly on the intended result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here ya go, not terribly elegant I will admit.  If you need to do this often it might be better to just create a table and add the values like it was suggested by Pondlife.

```
declare @date date
set @date = current_timestamp

declare @table table (dt date, interval varchar(10))
declare @interval time
set @interval = '00:00'
while @interval < '23:29'
begin
    insert into @table (dt,interval)
    select @date, 
        right('0000' + 
            substring(convert(varchar,@interval),1,2) + 
            substring(convert(varchar,@interval),4,2),4)
        + '-' + 
        right('0000' + 
            substring(convert(varchar,dateadd(minute,30,@interval)),1,2) + 
            substring(convert(varchar,dateadd(minute,30,@interval)),4,2),4)
    set @interval = dateadd(minute,30,@interval)
end

insert into @table (dt,interval)
select @date, '2330-0000'

select *
from @table
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using an inline table valued function that you can reuse to get any ranges you want for dates with any interval. You can derive the exact output you want by converting the datetime to a string and using string functions on that.

```
--A function that returns all intervals between start and end
CREATE FUNCTION GetTimeIntervals
(   
    @intervalMinutes int
    ,@startDateTime datetime
    ,@endDateTime datetime
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    WITH cSequence AS
    (
    SELECT  
        @startDateTime AS C_StartDateTime
        ,DATEADD(minute, @intervalMinutes, @startDateTime) AS C_EndDateTime

    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        C_EndDateTime AS C_StartDateTime
        ,DATEADD(minute, @intervalMinutes, C_EndDateTime) AS C_EndDateTime
    FROM cSequence 
    WHERE DATEADD(minute, @intervalMinutes, C_EndDateTime) <= @endDateTime
    )
    select C_StartDateTime, C_EndDateTime FROM cSequence
);

GO
--Example implementation
DECLARE @times TABLE (Id INT IDENTITY(1,1),time1 DATETIME,time2 DATETIME);
INSERT INTO @times VALUES ('2013-05-07 08:00','2013-05-07 10:00'),('2013-05-08','2013-05-09')
DECLARE @Interval INT = 30;

SELECT
Id
,fn.C_StartDateTime
,fn.C_EndDateTime
,REPLACE(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(16),fn.C_StartDateTime,121),5)+'-'+RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(16),fn.C_EndDateTime,121),5),':','') AS Interval
FROM @times AS t
CROSS APPLY GetTimeIntervals(@Interval,time1,time2) AS fn
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```